# Route controller and action in middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to retrieve the controller and action, I have tried to this point by using

```
var routeData = context.GetRouteData();
```

inside the middleware's Invoke method, but it yields null every time.

Is it possible at all to retrieve route data in middleware?

What I am trying to achieve is to check whether the requested action has a [RequireToken] attribute, and if so, it will check the incoming headers for a specific token.

Comment: No it is not possible to get route data in middleware. However you can do something like this: - `if (httpContext.Request.Path.ToString() == "/USA/Washington")` to find if the controller is USA and action is Washington.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The action/controller context is very specific to the MVC portion of the middleware pipeline. It is not possible to retrieve the Route Data outside of the MVC pipeline itself.

In order to achieve the desired behaviour, you should look at implementing an ActionFilter instead: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! I managed to manipulate the action result by using an ActionFilter and this solved my problem.